# How to Change Highlight Color of Opening and Closing Parentheses/Curly Braces in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, text-editor

I want to change the automatic highlight color of opening and closing parentheses/curly braces in Android Studio. The images below show the automatic highlighting that starts when you click on either the opening or closing parenthesis/curly brace. How can I change the highlight color from grey to another color for better readability?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to install a plugin named [Rainbow Brackets](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10080-rainbow-brackets) for that.
Just go to your `Plugins` > `Marketplace` and search for **Rainbow Brackets**
`Preferences > Plugins` for **Mac** and `File > Settings > Plugins` for **Windows**